# Multiple layouts with single style sheet

Tags: css, html, layout, stylesheet, overlapping

So I'm thinking I'm either missing something very obvious and setting myself up for a nasty fall or this is so obviously ok that no one really talks about it.

I want to use one style sheet for a small website, but I want a slightly different layout on some of the pages.

Example: Home Page would have right sidebar; another page would be full width; and another would possibly have three columns.

So that's it. What I'm creating is multiple `div` with different dimensions that would fit the various formats.

Ie. `#rightSide;` `#leftSide;` `#fullWidth;` `#middleContent`.

The idea is that I would use a certain combo of divs per page and the others would fade into the background until needed.

So I created the index page and it worked fine. It was a 3/4 width + rightSide. Now I'm creating a full width... and it still seems fine.

Yet all the research I do regarding multiple layouts on css insist that I use different style sheets even for small layout changes like double columns to full width.
I have seen zero reference to using CSS this way but maybe I'm using the wrong key words. Creating 3 or 4 stylesheets for a 6-8 page website seems a little excessive.

So what am I missing?

Comment: We have something called formatting and paragraphs, that thing is killing my eyes

Comment: I tried using that and it bounced me out of the box once, and made me submit a partially completed comment another time. So... I'm kind of scared to use it. :) But I will give it another try.

Comment: Have edited your question

Comment: Yes... I noticed. And here I thought I found a magic button.

Comment: Haha have you seen my answer

Answer (score 1):

Just have a style tag at the top of the pages that you want to have special features on then put all of your special style features in there

You could use nth-child selectors:

```
div.class:nth-child(1) { specific style for first}
```

Comment: Ummm.. I'm trying to understand exactly what you mean so I have been searching for the idiot's-guide. :) . The 'special features' refer to the various div dimensions. Do you mean specify a class? If I've already created a div (I'd have to have 3 in any case) what is the advantage to doing it that way?

Comment: Yes just add a class then in a style tag do you specific stuff

Comment: But I still have to create the three divs that will have a unique name. I can't reuse a single div and divide it into three. (Can I?) :) But I can see the value of reusing some of them. So ok. But what about the extra one? Will there be any surprises? Will it simply fade into the background? In effect, are you saying 'yes you can do that but do it more efficiently?'

Comment: Ahh ok so you want nth-child selectors like this `div.class:nth-child(1) { specific style for first}`

Comment: Ummm.. not quite sure how to answer that so I'll keep my mouth shut as that's never let me down. If the above nth child refers to specifying various dimensions of various divs that would essentially be coexisting over the same space... then yes. Note that I am not referring to colour/font styling/alignment or any other simple formatting... I am talking about reconstructing a parent contentWrapper that can contain multiple childContent divs within it that would NOT be used at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple you can user multiple classes for multiple page for example you can use css class for blogpage and use it in body tag
ur css will be like this

```
.menu{color:red}
.blogpage .menu {color:green}
```

and so on for each page

Comment: The formatting of colours/fonts/etc... is not my concern. I agree that's straight forward. It is the fact that I am creating separate columns/dividers within the body of the layout to organize the content that concerns me. One page will have two column layout, another three... so I will have overlapping divs although not all of them will be used at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can include the stylesheet on each page as normal but then overwrite the styling 'per page' to suite your needs:

Home page

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
<style>
/* Custome style for home page */
#rightSide {
    text-align: right;
}
</style>
</head>
```

Second page

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
<style>
/* Custome style for second page */
#leftSide {
    text-align: left;
}
</style>
</head>
```

**EDITED**

You could wrap each page in a container with an id of the page name. then target this within the CSS stylsheyy per page. eg

HTML

```
<div id="homePage">
    <div class="mainDiv">
    </div>
    <div id="rightSide">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#homePage .mainDiv {
    // style this home page only
}

#secondPage .mainDiv {
    // style this for second page
}
#homePage #rightSide {
    // style this home page only
}

#secondPage #rightSide {
    // style this for second page
}
```

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you are suggesting I use internal styling. If that's so...it kind of defeats the purpose. The whole point is that I want to maintain a single external stylesheet that can be adapted to hold the various page layouts. Or maybe I misunderstood?

Comment: You understood correctly. I thought your need for one stylesheet was to limit server calls to maintain optimum performance. In that case for maintainability i wouldn't use internal styling. See my Edit.

Comment: Never mind = that came out a mess. I cannot make a darn new line on this. I'll figure out another way.

Comment: So, you're saying that technically what I described above is ok? Example: If I created 6 divs within the contentWrapper, named BabyDiv1-6 (for simplicity). Each BabyDiv would have its own width. 900,500,400,300,300,300 respectively. Page 1 would use BabyDiv1; Page 2 would use BabyDiv4/5/6; Page 3 could use BabyDiv1 again... and the formatting could be done with class ids. And the other divs would not interfere if they are not being used? (That's my main concern).

Comment: Page 1 and page 2 could both use BabyDiv1, no need to create multiple div classes. `#page1 .BabyDiv1 { width: 300px;}` `#page2 .BabyDiv1 { width: 500px;}` this would not interfere with each other

Comment: Well, I would need at least three content divs if my largest layout has three columns. However, if the other pages have only one or two, then I could simply reuse them. So, to be clear, there is no downside to stacking the divs, because that is how I understand it. Which of course makes me wonder why this isn't suggested more often? Every reference to multiple layouts - even simple changes - says to either adjust the design or create a new style sheet. I haven't found any mention that you could do this, that's why I figured I was missing something.

Comment: Just a point for future reference if anyone wants to use this concept to make various page layouts: First, it does work. BUT...unless you really know what you're doing, DON'T use div classes to create a new content layout. Just create a new div id. Otherwise you will have headaches galore as a result of inherited formatting. I spent hours trying to figure out why my floats weren't clearing and why my formatting was working only in certain places.